# Помогите с расширением

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Мне надо написать расширение которое изменяет высоту строки на сайтах. Я сделал слайдер на `jquery ui`, но вот как мне сделать чтоб это значение применялось на сайте. Т.е. как передать значение в контент скрипт?
Это код слайдера:

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0.2,
    max: 4,
    step: 0.2,
    change: ari,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value"));

  function ari() {
    let slider = ($("#slider").slider("value"))
  }
});
```

Мне как-нибудь нужно передать переменную слайдер в контент скрипт не подскажите?

Comment: А вы ее прямо в контент крипте и создавайте. Разумеется добавив библиотеки jquey и jquery ui в код расширения, указав их в манифесте